# What does "spurned" modify in "I am walking out of a room to the jeers of a woman spurned"

Tags: meaning, sentence, syntactic-analysis, past-participles

> I am walking out of a room to the jeers of a woman spurned.

Which word does the past participle modify in this context?

Does it mean that I was spurned while walking out of the room, or am I out of the room to the jeers spurned of a woman?

Comment: What it *says* is that a woman [who had been] spurned jeered me as I walked out, but it doesn't make much sense. At a guess, what the author means is that 'I' is the 'woman' and that she is being jeered as she walks out for having just been publicly spurned. This reads like amateur fan-fiction.

Comment: It means you spurned the woman (typically meaning you  rejected her romantic or sexual advances), and in response she jeered you, as you were leaving the room. It's a allusion to the idiom "*Hell hath no fury like a woman scorned*", which has a similar meaning.

Comment: _A woman spurned_ is a fixed phrase, meaning _A woman who has been spurned_. One can also say _A spurned woman_, but that's not a fixed phrase. _A woman spurned_ falutes higher, since it's redolent of Victorian melodrama, which is appropriate for a self-descriptive puff like the sentence on display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the woman is spurned, not you. You're just being jeered at. If you were the spurned one, there would have to be a comma in there.

I am walking out of a room to the jeers of a woman, spurned.

In either case, you are being jeered at.